# How has becoming (grammatical structure)

Tags: grammar

I saw this question starts with 'How has becoming a pilot has enriched your life as a mother and wife?'. Could anyone please explain why the question phrase, how has becoming... - is grammatical correct?

Thanks a millions.

Comment: Compare "In what ways has passing your driving test made life easier?" Does a problem remain?

Comment: "How has becoming a pilot has" is wrong. The second "has" shouldn't be there. Is that the source of your uncertainty?

Comment: My main source of concern is How has becoming because I did not know becoming takes gerund form. Is it correct if I write "How has selling cakes made you financially stable?".

Answer (score 1):

*Becoming a pilot* is a [*gerund*](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/627/01/), also called *gerund participle*, and is the subject of your example sentence, just like *exercise* here:

> How has daily *exercise* enriched your life as a wife and mother?

What isn't grammatical is the insertion of an additional *has*:

> How has becoming a pilot <del>has</del> enriched your life as a mother and wife?

I have also reversed *mother and wife* because the order of those gender roles is virtually fixed in English.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. So, how has becoming (gerund) a pilot structure is the perfect tense indicating a change in a person's life whose career is a pilot? Thanks.

Comment: A gerund can have two tenses. I f you want past, it's _having become a pilot_. Is that what you were trying to do with the extra _has_?